# Probelm with vscode in show of menlo font family

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

today i opened vscode and saw i have problem with menlo font families in "i" char. not such this problem with Fira Code or Dejavu sans mono font. Anybody know why vscode show the font like this? (look at the highlighted words)
[image: this is the image]

Comment: Just depends on how ligatures are configured.

Comment: it means if i disable font ligatures it works correctly?

Comment: That's what ligatures look like when you put an `f` next to an `i`, but if you disable them you'll also have to give up the programming ones. My suggest, just find a different font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably turned on Font Ligatures. Try adding the following to your `settings.json`: `"editor.fontLigatures": false,`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).